# Returning false from checkbox's onclick function

Tags: javascript, checkbox, onclick

I want to take manual control over whether a given checkbox is checked. For this reason I provide a custom `onclick` function and `return false` from it: my thinking is if I don't `return false`, then the default action (revert the `input`'s `checked` flag) will override what I was setting in my custom function.

```js
let input = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0]

input.onclick = function() {
  if(input.checked)
    input.checked = false
  else
    input.checked = true
  
  return false
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox"/>
```

However, this doesn't work. `return false` reverts what I done! It resets the checkbox to the state it was in before clicking it!

Removing `return false` is no good either: Then the checkbox forces itself to the state it **wasn't** in before clicking it, again overriding whatever I do in my custom `onclick` function:

```js
let input = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0]

input.onclick = function() {
  if(input.checked)
    input.checked = true // click should be futile
  else
    input.checked = false //click should be futile
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox"/>
```

How can I take manual control over whether the checkbox is clicked or not? How can I make the checkbox not override whatever I set in my custom `onclick` handler?

Comment: I'm not sure what's happening but this seems to work: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/9mtby6es/

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do exactly, but be wary of using "onclick" with checkboxes. There's multiple ways to change a checkbox that don't involve clicking them, such as tabbing and pressing space, or using accessibility software. You're much better off watching the `change` event than the `click` event. `change` is what you truly care about (someone is attempting to change the state of the checkbox) anyways, whereas you don't really care HOW they do it (click or otherwise).

Comment: Also, it seems like your goal is to prevent the checkbox from changing. If so, then you should be disabling the checkbox (use the `disabled` attribute) instead of providing a confusing UX of allowing someone to try to change it, only for the box to revert.

Comment: @Nate Thank you for your remarks about the `change` event. As for what I'm trying to do: Implement a teambuilder for an online game. The user has to pick 8 monsters out of all available. For each monster the user has to pick some moves. So if the user tries to check the checkbox near an available monster but has not yet customized its moves I'd like to display a modal allowing the user to pick moves for this monster and delay checking the checkbox until the moves are filled in. Or if the moves are already customized, check the box immediately and save the team to cookies(still execute handler)

Comment: @Nate Which is why I don't want to flat out disable the box. I want to allow the user to check the checkbox. I just want to prompt them for additional data when they try to do this.

Comment: @Nate Though, I'm now trying to tab to a box and press space and it doesn't seem to bypass the `click` event. Maybe it's just Firefox tho

Answer (score 0):

Try returning values from the function instead of setting them:

```js
let input = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0]

input.onclick = function() {
  if(input.checked)
    return true // click should be futile
  else
    return false //click should be futile
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox"/>
```

Here, the value of the checkbox cannot be modified once it is checked. Is this what you were after?

Comment: Thank you, though I'm not sure what's going on here? I mean when the box is not checked, the handler returns `false` and yet clicking it checks it. So what does `return false` actually do? The only two possible semantics I can see are either (a) set the box to unchecked or (b) set the box to the state it was before clicking it. (a) is not the case because the box gets checked. (b) is not the case either since the box was unchecked before clicking it and yet it gets set to checked. So what is going on here? What are the semantics of `return false`?

Comment: @gaazkam Well try swapping the two `return` statements around - it prevents the checkbox from being checked. Essentially, my code locks the checkbox in a certain state once it meets that state - that state is whichever part of the `if-else` statement contains the `return true`. If you switch the `return` statements, you can't check the checkbox - it'll be locked in the unchecked state.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to do this? If you want set state of the checkBox according to some data there are easy ways. Or if you want to trigger changing checkbox’s state from a different place you should add onClick event somewhere else rather than the checkBox’s itself.

Comment: Why do I want to do this? I'm trying to implement a teambuilder for an online game. The user has to pick 8 monsters out of all available. For each monster the user has to pick some moves. So if the user tries to check the checkbox near an available monster but has not yet customized its moves I'd like to display a modal allowing the user to pick moves for this monster and delay checking the checkbox until the moves are filled in. Or if the moves are already customized, check the box immediately and save the team to cookies(still execute handler)

Answer (score 0):

I reverted your true and false. If condition does not met use this.  If mets use otherwise. After you choose the movements of the monsters set value of the checkBox from the modal.

```js
let input = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0]

input.onclick = function() {
  if(input.checked)
    input.checked = false
  else
    input.checked = true 
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox"/>
```

```js
let input = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0]

input.onclick = function() {
  if(input.checked)
    input.checked = true // click should be futile
  else
    input.checked = false //click should be futile
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox"/>
```